# Log Unhandled Exceptions in WPF Application to SQL database

Tags: wpf, logging

I am working with a WPF application with VS2017.

I would like some advice on the best way log exceptions to a SQL server database in WPF using C#?

I want to be able to capture any exception at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on these two events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

Your code could look like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    InitializeComponent();
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender,     
{
    Exception eee = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    MethodBase met = eee.TargetSite;
    MessageBox.Show("fatal error in method: " + met.Name
        + Environment.NewLine + eee.GetType().ToString() +
    Environment.NewLine + eee.Message, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    InsertIntoDatebase("insert into errors (datetime, error) values ('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "', '" + e.Message + "'");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

void InsertIntoDatebase(string sql)
{
    // do it as usually, it depends what SQL database you use
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a WPF app I work on, we capture three exception-related events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => HandleException(args.ExceptionObject as Exception);
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) => HandleException(args.Exception);
DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, args) => HandleException(args.Exception);
```

However, rather than trying to manually get a database connection going and brewing up some SQL in the event handler, I'd much rather rely on a 3rd party library that I know can do the job well.

I'd strongly recommend looking at configuring a solution like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and it's implementation of [ADO appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html). You'll also be able to set up logging to file, easily change the configuration without rebuilding the app, and provide logging to the rest of your application.